# Decimal module and complex numbers in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way for manipulating complex numbers in more than floating point precision using python?

For example to get a better precision on real numbers I can easily use the `Decimal` module. However it doesn't appear to work with complex numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.

[gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) supports extended precision integer, rational, real, and complex numbers. It also supports a variety of scientific functions.

Another alternative is [mpmath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mpmath). `mpmath` is written in pure Python so it may be easier to install. If `gmpy2` is available, it will be used automatically to improve performance. `mpmath` supports a wider variety of functions.

Note that both `gmpy2` and `mpmath` support binary (radix-2) floating point arithmetic while the `Decimal` module supports decimal (radix-10) arithmetic.

Comment: I'm curious what the implications of your last sentence are?

Comment: @DylanYoung https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/ - TLDR `gmpy2` and `mpmath` might be less accurate than the decimal module, if I understood the last sentence correctly.

Comment: For my purpose, I need to use decimal arithmetic. Is there a similar module that supports complex numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything built-in. You'd have to implement it yourself, or use a third-party library.

Comment: Are you sure? Can I modify the original module to make it work with complex numbers? How can I implement it otherwise?