# How do I get a Decimal square root of a negative Decimal number in Python?

Tags: python, decimal

To get the sqaure root of a negative number we could use cmath.sqrt. But either the real part or the imag part of the result is still a float:

`type (cmath.sqrt (Decimal (-8)).imag)`

result: float

How do I get a Decimal square root of a negative Decimal number?

For a positive number we could use: `Decimal (8).sqrt ()`

The result is still a Decimal. But it doesn't work on negative numbers: `Decimal (-8).sqrt ()`

{InvalidOperation}[]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decimal module and complex numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500275/decimal-module-and-complex-numbers-in-python)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille For `cmath()` yes, but in general, like `complex` is essentially a 2-tuple of `float` `(float, float)` you could extend the `decimal` module to handle `complex` numbers as a 2-tuple of `Decimal`. It is just not implemented.

Comment: How much complex number functionality do you actually need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a `ComplexDecimal()` class with that functionality.

Here is some code to get you going:

```
from decimal import Decimal


class ComplexDecimal(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.real = Decimal(value.real)
        self.imag = Decimal(value.imag)

    def __add__(self, other):
        result = ComplexDecimal(self)
        result.real += Decimal(other.real)
        result.imag += Decimal(other.imag)
        return result

    __radd__ = __add__

    def __str__(self):
        return f'({str(self.real)}+{str(self.imag)}j)'

    def sqrt(self):
        result = ComplexDecimal(self)
        if self.imag:
            raise NotImplementedError
        elif self.real > 0:
            result.real = self.real.sqrt()
            return result
        else:
            result.imag = (-self.real).sqrt()
            result.real = Decimal(0)
            return result
```

```
x = ComplexDecimal(2 + 3j)
print(x)
# (2+3j)
print(x + 3)
# (5+3j)
print(3 + x)
# (5+3j)

print((-8) ** (0.5))
# (1.7319121124709868e-16+2.8284271247461903j)
print(ComplexDecimal(-8).sqrt())
# (0+2.828427124746190097603377448j)
print(type(ComplexDecimal(8).sqrt().imag))
# <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

and then you need to implement multiplication, division, etc. yourself, but that should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks so much for the kind help! It indeed works, but I do have to ask a dumb question: how do I implement multiplication and stuff?

Comment: @Mason You need to implement the respective methods, e.g. `__mul__` and `__rmul__` for multiplication. See the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html) for a list of the methods that you may want to implement. Of course, you have to work out the math yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can do `x ** 0.5` where x is a negative number, for example:

```
>>> x = -10
>>> x ** 0.5
(1.9363366072701937e-16+3.1622776601683795j)
```

Comment: This will not return a `Decimal`-based value and `Decimal(-10) ** 0.5` will just throw a `TypeError`, while `Decimal(-10) ** Decimal(0.5)` will throw a `InvalidOperation`.